# Type parameter must be contravariantly valid

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting, factory

Consider a bird:

```
public interface IBird
{

}

public class Duck : IBird
{
    public string DuckyProperty { get; set; } //this property is Duck specific!
}
```

And a bird processor:

```
public interface IBirdProcessor<out T> where T : IBird
{
    double GetBirdWeight(T obj); //this does not compile
}

public class DuckProcessor : IBirdProcessor<Duck>
{
    public double GetBirdWeight(Duck duck)
    {
        return double.Parse(duck.DuckyProperty);
    }
}
```

And a factory to get a bird processor:

```
public class BirdProcessorFactory
{
    public IBirdProcessor<T> GetBirdProcessor<T>(T obj) where T : IBird
    {
        return (IBirdProcessor<T>)new DuckProcessor();
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
static void Main()
{
    var bird = new Duck() { DuckyProperty = "23" } as IBird; //the cast is necessary to simulate a real world scenario
    var factory = new BirdProcessorFactory();
    var provider = factory.GetBirdProcessor(bird);

    var weight = provider.GetBirdWeight(bird);
}
```

I want to have an abstract generic bird factory but I get the following error instead:

```
The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'Program.IBirdProcessor<T>.GetBirdWeight(T)'. 'T' is covariant
```

If I remove 'out' keyword then I get:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'DuckProcessor' to type 'IBirdProcessor`1[NotVegetables.Program+IBird]'.'
```

The cast won't work!

As a workaround I can do  this:

```
public class DuckProcessor : IBirdProcessor<IBird>
{
    public double GetBirdWeight(IBird bird)
    {
        var duck = bird as Duck;
        return double.Parse(duck.DuckyProperty);
    }
}
```

But this defies usage of generics at all, I feel like DuckProcessor  should work with ducks, not with abstract birds.

Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: @Fildor - still doesnt work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jR2Reh

Comment: Hm ... let me look again. Yep, was wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Don't think there is another way around then to let `DuckProcessor` also implement `IBirdProcessor<IBird>` see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/V6I8Jm

Comment: @RandRandom if so then there is no real point in doing generics, right? I can just get off with IBirds everywhere and casting. But that feels very weird

Comment: Why not just add a `Weight` property to `IBird`?

Comment: @NickFarsi - but without it what should happen on `((IBirdProcessor<IBird>)new DuckProcessor()).GetBirdWeight(new Sparrow()))` how should `DuckProcessor` handle a `Sparrow`?

Comment: Errr. you are casting to `IBirdProcessor<IBird>` not `IBirdProcessor<Duck>`- I think that is the point, no?

Comment: @RandRandom it would need an implementation of SparrowProcessor : IBirdProcessor<Sparrow> and an if statement in factory

Comment: @NickFarsi - that didn't answer my question, I wanted to know how a `DuckProcessor` should handle a `Sparow` since you want to be able to cast `DuckProcessor` to `IBirdProcessor<IBird>` it needs to be able to handle all classes inheriting `IBird`, you will not end up with the explicit `IBirdProcessor<Duck>`.

Comment: @RandRandom it should not handle it, but the Factory won't return DuckProcessor if given a Sparrow anyway!

Comment: @NickFarsi -  `but the Factory won't return DuckProcessor if given a Sparrow anyway!` the instance it returns does not matter, the method will return a type of `IBirdProcessor<IBird>` and the type safety needs to be enforced and your method will return an `IBirdProcessor<IBird>` - not a `DuckProcess`, not a `SparrowProcessor` - but the type `IBirdProcessor<IBird>` simpliefied: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YAdy8e - `xyz` is of type `object` even though you pass a string to the method `GetValue`, `GetValue` will return the type `object` and it doesnt matter what the instance actually is

Comment: I think the main problem here is that IBird is non-generic while everything else is (or derived from a generic or implementing a generic). So _everything_ always boils down to not knowing what Bird the IBird actually is at the right time. And maybe a shift to composition would make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. For now I suppose I will stick to @RandRandom's solution that involves casting.

Comment: _"Am I doing something completely wrong?"_ - I would argue that most correct approach would be just having `GetBirdWeight` as part of `IBird` (or just get only property `Weight{get;}`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the types in C# generics have to be known at compile time. Only `IBird` is known at compile time, and the factory has to return an `IBirdProcessor<IBird>`. Since covariancy isn't an option (because `DuckProcessor.GetBirdWeight` only accepts `Duck`s), a `DuckProcessor` cannot be returned.

You can kind of get the behavior you are wanting with:

```
public interface IBirdProcessor
{
  double GetBirdWeight(IBird obj);
}

public abstract class BirdProcessorBase<T> : IBirdProcessor where T : IBird
{
  public double GetBirdWeight(IBird bird) => GetBirdWeightInternal((T)bird);

  protected abstract double GetBirdWeightInternal(T bird);
}

public class DuckProcessor : BirdProcessorBase<Duck>
{
  protected override double GetBirdWeightInternal(Duck duck)
  {
    return double.Parse(duck.DuckyProperty);
  }
}

public class BirdProcessorFactory
{
  public IBirdProcessor GetBirdProcessor(IBird bird)
  {
    if (bird.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(Duck)))
      return new DuckProcessor();

    throw new Exception($"No processor for {bird.GetType().Name}");
  }
}
```

Though if you ever call the processor returned from the factory with a type that doesn't match, it will throw exceptions at you.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my solution for the problem:

```
public interface IBird
{

}

public class Duck : IBird
{
    public string DuckyProperty { get; set; } //this property is Duck specific!
}

public class Chicken : IBird
{
    public string ChickenProperty { get; set; } //this property is Chicken specific!
}

public interface IBirdProcessor<Y>
    where Y : IBird
{
    double GetBirdWeight(Y obj);
}

public class DuckProcessor : IBirdProcessor<Duck>
{

    public double GetBirdWeight(Duck duck)
    {
        return double.Parse(duck.DuckyProperty);
    }
}

public class ChickenProcessor : IBirdProcessor<Chicken>
{
    public double GetBirdWeight(Chicken chicken)
    {
        return double.Parse(chicken.ChickenProperty);
    }
}

public class BirdProcessorFactory
{
    public static IBirdProcessor<T> GetProcessor<T>(T bird)
        where T : IBird
    {
        switch (bird){
            case Chicken t1:
                return (IBirdProcessor<T>)new ChickenProcessor();
            case Duck t1:
                return (IBirdProcessor<T>)new DuckProcessor();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        
    }
}
```

To show that it works as expected, I have added additional `ChickenProcessor`.

And the execution looks like next:

```
Duck duck = new Duck() { DuckyProperty = "23" };
Chicken chicken = new Chicken() { ChickenProperty = "25" };

var duckProvider = BirdProcessorFactory.GetProcessor(duck);
var chickenProvider = BirdProcessorFactory.GetProcessor(chicken);

duckProvider.GetBirdWeight(duck).Dump();
chickenProvider.GetBirdWeight(chicken).Dump();
```

And result is as expected:

[image]

Comment: Problem is, you know the type at runtime, whereas factory approach is supposed to work with generic (or abstract) types and accept any bird. So in fact you completely removed factory from the issue.

Comment: @NickFarsi Thanks for the explanation, so you basically needed a factory method, which will take the right processor. I have adjusted a code.

Comment: Casting DuckProcessor to IBirdProcessor<IBird> will result into runtime exception, a lot like in my original example